# Runtime exception - Datanucleus and GAE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I am newbie to Google app engine and Data nucleus. The following error seems like some jar issue but i am not sure which jars of Data nucleus should be in my war/web-inf/classes folder and which jars should be in app engine SDK folder. I am using App engine SDK 1.7.0. i get no problem in data nucleus enhancement.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(Lorg/datanucleus/PersistenceConfiguration;Lorg/datanucleus/ClassLoaderResolver;)V
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:159)
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:141)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseOMFContext(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:144)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseProperties(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:316)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:260)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:71)
<continued in next message>
```

In the app engine SDK folder there are various other folders and they contain different versions of same data nucleus file.

****EDIT: ****
After updating the SDK to 1.7.3 i noticed the following JARS in the appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3\lib\user\orm folder and these are datanucleus jars presennt there.

```
datanucleus-core-1.1.5
datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5
datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final
jdo2-api-2.3-eb
```

My war/web-inf/lib contains all the above jars and following jars too:

```
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.3.jar
```

My exception has changed and now it is:

```
    2012-12-12 12:49:17.397
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: Bundle "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" requires "org.datanucleus" version "3.1.1" but the resolved bundle has version "3.1.1" which is outside the expected range.
E 2012-12-12 12:49:17.534
org.datanucleus.api.ApiAdapterFactory getApiAdapter: Error : An error occurred trying to instantiate an instance of the adapter "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter" : NUCLEUS_CONTEXT_LOADER
W 2012-12-12 12:49:18.182
org.datanucleus.OMFContext setApi: There is no available API adapter "JDO". Using existing adapter.
E 2012-12-12 12:49:18.182
org.datanucleus.api.ApiAdapterFactory getApiAdapter: Error : An error occurred trying to instantiate an instance of the adapter "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter" : Could not initialize class org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOAdapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appengine JDO/JPA plugin Wiki [defines well enough](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility) what DataNucleus jars are needed with each version of the plugin

Comment: I had not installed Data nucleus plugin, only google plugin for app engine was there. Now i have installed Data nucleus plugin 2.0.4. The compatibility page states that  version 2 requires DataNucleus 3.0+ (core, api-jdo, api-jpa, enhancer). I have 2 questions now:
1-My google app engine (1.7.0) SDK also contains data nucleus Jar files inside user/orm folder. Do i need to upgrade those jars too?
2- what to do after installing the data nucleus plugin in eclipse?

Comment: There is no such things as GAE JDO/JPA plugin v2.0.4. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/orm/datanucleus-appengine/

Comment: Way easier just to upgrade your AppEngine SDK to the latest (1.7.3?) and you get all you need installed with that. Why you're going off down the route of installing some unrelated Eclipse plugin I dunno

Comment: opt/user/datanucleus/v2 has all jars that are needed, as per the instructions in AppEngine https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2  Their docs tell you how to upgrade